# File permission to PHP uploaded image

Tags: php, html

In my PHP site I have a script to upload images, see the script below

```
$uploaddir = $root_path."images/uploaded_images/category/"; 
            $small_file_name = trim($_FILES['cat_image1']['name']);
            $small_file_len = strlen($small_file_name);
            $small_file_ext = strtolower(substr($small_file_name,-4)); // select last 4 characters
            $small_uploadfile = $uploaddir. $_FILES['cat_image1']['name'];  
            if($small_file_len>4 and ($small_file_ext==".gif" or $small_file_ext==".jpg" or $small_file_ext=="jpeg")){
                if ($small_file_ext=="jpeg")
                    $uniqname = uniqid(rand()).".".$small_file_ext;
                else
                    $uniqname = uniqid(rand()).$small_file_ext;
                $thumb_filename1 = "thumb_".$uniqname;  //  store uniqname into database
                $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$uniqname; //uncomment for local testing 
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cat_image1']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                    chmod($uploadfile,0777);
                    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($uploadfile);
                    $max_width = 276;
                    $max_height = 162;
                    $a = new Thumbnail($uploadfile,$max_width,$max_height,$uploaddir.$thumb_filename1,100,'');
                    $a->create();

                }else{  
                        $flag=1;
                        $frm_server_side_error= $frm_server_side_error."Error in uploading image,";
                }
            }
            else{
                $flag=2;
                $frm_server_side_error= $frm_server_side_error."Image not in gif or jpg format,";

            }
```

After uploading in to the server its can't be see (I am displaying the thumb image). So I checked the file permission of that image through the FTP and give read permission. Thus image displays. But I give the read and write permission to the category folder and it’s parent folders. How can view the image after uploading (default read permission to the uploading files ie thumb image.)

I noticed that the actual image have read permission but the thumb image doesn't have the read permission. I need to display only the thumb image.

Comment: What OS is your server running?

Comment: What do the parameters represent of `new Thumbnail();`? And you have already used `chmod($uploadfile,0777);`. Perhaps you can do this too on the new file? (`$uploaddir.$thumb_filename1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a class Thumbnail to create a thumbnail image. But I guess you have missed to change the file permission in the new thumbnail image. Please check the code in the create() function of the class Thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Your code formatted poorly here (half is in code format, half not), but it appears you have a comment before the snippet that would copy the file from the temp location to the final location - if that's the case, the file won't exist, and thus won't be viewable.

But I could be wrong - I'm happy to take a second look if you fix the formatting.